# Java: Vector<String> warnings

Tags: java, string, generics, vector

```
public class myTokens
{
     protected Vector<String> myTokens;

     ...

     public Vector<String> getTokens ()
     {
          return myTokens;
     }
}

...

public class otherClass
{
...

    public Vector<String> myStrings ()
    {
    ...

        return myTokens.getTokens ();
    }
}
```

While using Eclipse, the method myStrings at the return myTokens.getTokens () is marked as a warning saying "The expression of type Vector needs unchecked conversion to conform to Vector"

The dang method says it returns a `Vector<String>` why is this marked as a warning?

The only way I can deal with this is to use a suppress warning pragma which in itself in Eclipse marks as a warning so in essence in Eclipse it is impossible to deal with this warning.

Thanx for your Help.

Bodger

Comment: Can you post a complete, minimal test-case?

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you have two separate classes, and you're attempting to draw values from one class into the other.

Comment: I've voted to close, because this question can't be answered unless we see some *actual* code (see http://sscce.org).

Comment: This is confusing, because there's a class called `myTokens`, with a field called `myTokens`; and there's also another variable `myTokens` which is referenced in `otherClass`. To answer the question, we'd need to know the type of the `myTokens` that's referenced inside `otherClass`.  I suggest to Bodger that he/she renames each of these things, for the sake of clarity (with a capital letter for the name of the class).  It might then become clear what the problem is.  If not, then post the rest of the code, in particular the declaration of the third `myTokens`, and I'll take another look.

Comment: Alright, I do not know what is going on.  I wrote a minimal test case and it worked as expected.  The code classes involved in my main program are way too large and complex their must be some extenuating circumstances that I cannot determine.  If I can close this I will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Vector classes were made obsolete by the JDK1.2 and should probable not be used in new development. You should try to use another class instead.

What netbeans gives me:

> This inspection reports any uses of java.util.Vector or
>   java.util.Hashtable. While still supported, these classes were made
>   obsolete by the JDK1.2 collection classes, and should probably not be
>   used in new development.

Comment: This is true.  But it's not the cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: That's not correct; I haven't seen anything to suggest deprecation or obsolescence in the documentation.  From the [Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/):  "As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector."

Comment: `Vector` is unofficially deprecated. The only time it seems to be used is with beginner code (old text books?) and as parameters for a few Swing classes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want something like dynamic array, use lists. [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is fine.

Comment: I know. But if he'll use lists, there should be no warning.

Comment: There should be no warning anyway.  The OP hasn't posted his/her real code.

Comment: I could post my code but it is much larger so I just posted snippets

Comment: @Bodger: It should always be possible to reduce the code down to a minimal test-case that still compiles (or still shows the single compiler error, in this case).  Again, I suggest you take a look at http://sscce.org.